# Find out formname and progname from EXPORT statement?

Tags: abap, alv

This maybe sound like a silly question but: I've got this Line in my Code:
It's part of a piece of code I found online, to edit fields using CL_SALV_TABLE.

```
EXPORT formname FROM 'OPEN_FIELDS_FOR_EDITING' progname FROM sy-repid TO MEMORY ID 'CL_SALV_TABLE'.
```

So, "formname" is the name of my script, right? But what is "progname"? And where do I find this name?

Comment: Ah, the joys of "found this somewhere on da interwebs"-code... Be aware that what you are attempting to do is almost certainly not supported by SAP and might have very grave consequences unless you really know what you're doing - which, judging by the questions you post, you don't.

Comment: You probably found it here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sap-cl-salv-table/files/

Answer (score 0):

A more sensible way of formatting the code would be

```
EXPORT formname FROM 'OPEN_FIELDS_FOR_EDITING' 
       progname FROM sy-repid 
  TO MEMORY ID 'CL_SALV_TABLE'.
```

If you check the keyword documentation that is available through F1 in your system [as well as online](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapexport_data_cluster_param.htm), you will see that both `formname` and `progname` are just names.

Answer (score 0):

The formname is the name of a form within a report. The progname is the name of a report. Have a look at the system variables to understand what sy-repid is.
Forms are subroutines you can use to separate different parts of a report. 
You might find this helpful:
https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenabap_subroutines.htm